# File upload using ftp_fput not working in case of image

Tags: php, ftp

I have tried file upload to server using ftp connection in php and it works fine for html file but in case of images, directories are created but no image will be upload in this directories....i have tried following code please help by correcting it

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

$my_file = "PATH_TO_FILE";

$fp = fopen($my_file, "r");

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $my_file , $fp , FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded \n";
} else {
       echo "There was a problem while uploading \n";
}

fclose($fp);
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: if there a reason you are passing a file handle to ftp_fput vs passing a filename to ftp_put

Comment: also with error reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors on does it give you anything

Comment: What do you get when you run that script? Does it echo success or failure? Also, have your triple-checked that the $my_file really exists, andthat fopen() did not return FALSE?

Comment: @orangepill thanks forasking....yes i have pass a file handle because same function will be used to upload html files and images and html file are created first.. so i think it is the best way to upload...if it is not a proper way to use ftp_put please  help me with valid code...

Comment: @Alex-Info.net it gives success in both case and i found html files on the server but not the images....all the path are proper i have checked it so many time

Comment: ftp_put you would forego your fopen and just do `ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_filename, $local_filename, FTP_BINARY);

Comment: and since you are using $my_file make sure it makes sense on both the local machine and the server.

Comment: i have tried that one also but it gives an error 3 parameter in ftp_put requires resource not string...

Comment: @Angiel i have used that one..please see in the posted code..

Comment: I doubt that using $my_file for BOTH the **local** path/file and the **remote** path/file is really what you want. Use a full path to the local file and another (most probably different) full path (relative to the FTP) for the remote file. Also, try without the fopen() if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net no it is also not working....

Comment: also for html files they are uploaded properly when we upload first time but on second time if same file is uploaded it gives an error Cannot STOR. No permission.

Comment: if your html file already exist and you have no rights to overwirte it (which seems to be your case) try ftp_delete() first.

Comment: @Alex-Info.net Thanks for the reply...for HTML file it works fine after delete but the case of images is still the same....please help for that also...Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a silly mistake for image upload i have used ftp_fput instead of ftp_put....using ftp_put it is working fine code for image upload and file upload are given below:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect("FTP_SERVER");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "FTP_USERNAME", "FTP_PASSWORD");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

/*Image Upload*/
if (ftp_put($conn_id, "REMOTE_SERVER_PATH", "LOCAL_SERVER_PATH",  FTP_BINARY)) {
echo "Successfully uploaded \n";

} else {
echo "ERROR IN FTP UPLOAD";
}

/* HTML UPLOAD */

$fp = fopen("LOCAL_FILE_PATH", "r");

if (ftp_fput($conn_id, "PATH_WHERE_TO_UPLOAD/FILENAME.html" , $fp , FTP_ASCII)) {
echo "Successfully uploaded \n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading \n";
}

fclose($fp);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Thanks to all for there help.... :-)